# How to serialize and deserialize an open file object?

Tags: python, serialization

Is there a way to serialize and deserialize an open file-object, such that the deserialized object is an object with same characteristics as the serialized one (i.e., full-path, opening mode, offset, internal buffers, etc.)?

Code-wise, it would be something like that:

```
import some_pickle_like_module as splm

with open("infile.bin", "rb") as fp:
    first17bytes = fp.read(17)

    with open("infile.splm", "wb") as pkl:
        splm.dump(fp, pkl)

# and later in the code:

with open("infile.splm", "rb") as pkl:
    fp = splm.load(pkl)

next17bytes = fp.read(17)
fp.close()
```

Note that this example is somewhat trivial (because I could dump() and load() the file's name and offset), but the same could apply to compressed files, where seeking to a given location could be very slow.

Comment: The question was somewhat misleading. I edited it to clarify that it is not about pickle's spec and capabilities, but rather about a module (with similar simple dump()/load() funcs) that can do that for files (and hopefully compressed files as well).

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not possible. Proof: if you close the file-descriptor there is no way to reobtain the old object from unpickling without re-opening the file. File objects are defined by the OS kernel and python doesn't have control on that, and thus cannot pickle them. The only way is to pickle the path, mode and byte offset and, when unpickling, re-open the file and move to the correct position.

In any case I don't think it's a good idea to pickle files at all, because the file might be deleted and the unpickling would fail. Just pickle/unpickle the contents.

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle technically you can do this with pickle protocol v2, but it's sort of documented bug... Also, as stated in post, results doesn't make any sense when unpickling.

Comment: @Wikiii122 I fail to see how the link you posted is relevant to the question. The examples are *not* pickling file objects, they are simply pickling some object *into* a specific file. The OP has asked about a completely different use case.

Comment: Sorry, they don't let linking to sections... Section "What can you pickle?", last paragraph `With pickle protocol v2, you are able to pickle open file objects.` And it does work in some versions of CPython (a few versions after 2.3 and beetween 3.0 and 3.2 I believe made it possible). You just are unable to use unpickled object in any useful way. It's just a sidenote, that if you can pickle it, doesn't mean it has worked.

Comment: @Wikiii122 Don't trust the wiki. Trust the official documentation. The section [What can be pickled and unpickled?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled) does **not** list open file objects (nor closed file objects). Whether there is a bug that allows to pass file objects without an error being raised is a completely different matter. The fact is: the functionality isn't implemented. And *cannot* be implemented because file objects are wrappers around file descriptors which are handled by the OS. You can't implement that without the OS cooperation