# Serializable file object

Tags: python, redis, celery

Trying to get an answer to a similar question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561431/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-an-open-file-object). I have a celery task that generates a file (pdf), that then needs to be sent back into redis so that the API can serve it to the end user.

What is the best way to create a serializable file object that will keep a filename property associated with it? It works fine with bytesIO, but the API has no idea about the file it's handling, and therefore doesn't know what filename to give it in the response.

I believe the best method to achieve this workflow is to deploy minio or another object store that can handle the lifecycle of the file objects. We already have redis deployed, and given that the lifespan of the objects are just a matter of minutes; redis should be fine for this job.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context here to clarify what you're trying to do? I'm not clear why your celery task doesn't simply return the filename...

Comment: I agree with @larsks. Even though you can store binary objects on Redis, it's not the best idea. I would simply use some other kind of storage for the file (local filesystem, S3, ... depending on your exact use case) and return the file location from the task as a result.

Comment: Why don't you make the celery task store the file_name as another property along with the file in Redis?

Comment: Thanks all. I have added some more details to the question. File storage is not ideal as the API is in a separate pod to the celery worker, and the lifecycles of the files would have to be manually handled.

Comment: @codeness93 good idea. I wanted to keep the binary contained with the other information (filename), and was thinking there may be a serializable structure that can do this. I think right now I might just have the Celery task return {'filename': 'my_file.pdf', 'payload': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7f8d2f23de00>}

Answer (score 1):

If the generated PDF files are not too large it should be trivial to store them in Redis. Keep in mind that everything stored in Redis is a binary blob anyway. Even if they are large you may encounter some cache evictions done by Redis. With clever expiry strategy it should all be fine with a decent Redis server.

The real problem is if you want to pass PDF file to your Celery tasks. Do not do that. Instead, pass a Redis key to your Celery tasks, so it knows where to grab the content of the PDF file from (or S3 key, or similar). This is a good strategy for anything, in general (do not pass large objects to Celery tasks). Why is it so? - Because the task args and metadata in general are stored for a long time.

Comment: Thanks Dejan. In fact I am only passing the file from the Celery task into the Redis store (and not vice-versa), and will configure a suitable TTL to ensure we don't waste too much space.

Comment: The problem I am running into, however, is storing the PDF document in the Redis store as a blob but with its file attributes so that when it is recalled, it can be deserialized to serve the file with the appropriate filename.

Comment: File attributes like? Size? Modification time?

Comment: Just filename to begin with.

Comment: Filename is perfect candidate to be your Redis key. I do not get what the problem is. You can store whatever you like in Redis along the binary blob itself, either as separate keys, or in a hash (using HSET etc)

Comment: Thanks Dejan, The problem with making the filename the key is that the API service that is querying redis for the results does not know what the filename is. Right now we can reference the results by the Celery task ID created when the task is created, but other than that, the API has no idea how to find the result.

Comment: Then  use the task ID as the key for your hash, and store everything you need there.

Comment: I got it working by writing a serializable class that contains the bytearray and the filename and can return a Django FileResponse. This is implemented on bother the Celery task and API, and seems to work fine